# Launch VLC Player through Java

Tags: java, vlcj

I want to launch my VLC player through a Java program, can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to control VLC by java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768397/how-to-control-vlc-by-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vlc is located on different places depending on your system, but this is for 64 bit

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "file to start with vlc");
Process start = pb.start();
```

and this should work for x86:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "file to start with vlc");
Process start = pb.start();
```

Comment: backslashes (\\) should be escaped: "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"

Comment: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C://ProgramFiles/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe", "D://avtar.mp4");
Process start = pb.start();                                       The Vlc player is opening for me but its not playing the video from the specified path.

Comment: I am done with this problem the solution is something like this, you should paste the  video file into yours workspace/yoursapplication/a.pm4

Answer (score 4):

Use VLCJ. [Here is the new link](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this sample of code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path_to_your_VLC_exe");
```

Unfortunately you will need to have an absolute path to your executable file, which sometimes cannot be obtained.

Look here for more examples: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Comment: You may want to obtain it from the **user** ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"E:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\"");

      System.out.println("VLC started.");

   }
}
```

Comment: It is unlikely that it is contained in E:

Comment: What if i want to play a file with VLC ?

Comment: Usually, the first argument of any executable that works with files is the path of the file to open... for example: "vlc.exe MyVideo.mov"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify an absolute path to the program, which might be a problem if you do not know where VLC is stored.