# Trouble with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, runtime.exec, processbuilder

Following code opens status very fine in notepad:

```
import java.util.*;
class test
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try{
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("notepad","F:/status");
    pb.start();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Following code does'not play the song:

```
import java.util.*;
class test
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try{
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc","D:/02 Tu Jaane Na");
    pb.start();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try with this `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe` and `D:\\02 Tu Jaane Na.mp3` and take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171840/launch-vlc-player-through-java

Comment: What happens? Does it print out an exception? Does it launch VLC at all? Also, generally 'e.printStackTrace();` gives you more information than `System.out.println(e);`.

Comment: @ RanRag : but why did not it worked with (/) ??

Comment: @ Martin McNulty : no it works fine but does not play the song.it just display the vlc player's screen

Comment: @shubhendumahajan: AFAIK, it should work with either \\ or /, the difference is that RanRag added the file extension `.mp3` to the filename

Comment: please post output of `dir "D:/02 Tu Jaane Na"`

Answer (score 2):

For 1.6+ code, use [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) instead.

---

Of course, the sensible thing to do immediately before calling that is to check [`File.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29).

OTOH, `Desktop.open(File)` throws a slew of handy exceptions, including:

- `NullPointerException` - if file is null
- **`IllegalArgumentException` - if the specified file doesn't exist**
- `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the current platform does not support the `Desktop.Action.OPEN` action
- `IOException` - if the specified file has no associated application or the associated application fails to be launched

Properly handled, the exception would indicate the immediate problem.

---

As an aside, the `Desktop` class is designed to be cross-platform, and will handle any file type for which an association is defined.  In that sense it is a lot more useful for something like this, than trying to use a `Process`.

Comment: Desktop.open will open an associated application. In Windows association is done via file extension only, and the file he(?) tries to open is called `D:/02 Tu Jaane Na` so Desktop.open will fail

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you're ignoring the fact that the files you're trying to open have [filename extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension).

Windows Explorer doesn't display file extensions by default - that is probably why you are not aware of their existence.

The reason why notepad worked in your first example is that notepad automatically adds `.txt` extension to its filename parameter in case you didn't provide one yourself. So in reality the file that is being open is not `status` but `status.txt`.

VLC doesn't have this "advanced" functionality because there's no specific filename extension it is designed to work with.

So you will need to look up the `dir` command output and add the full file name as a parameter.

If that was the real issue - you might want to modify your Windows Explorer settings for it to display file extensions:

[image]

or, which is better, switch to a more programmer-friendly OS :)