# why i cannot open mp3 file using window media player using java

Tags: java, file

I need to open mp3 file in windows media player in java. getting an error. 
codes are as follows

```
File f=new File("D:\\songsmain\\kolaveri.mp3"); // path of the mp3 free
Desktop d1=Desktop.getDesktop();
d1.open(f);
```

Comment: Please tell us something about your error, for example a stacktrace?

Comment: which error? have you set default player windows media player?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @home: the error thrown is IOException:Failed to open file:file path. Error message: Access is denied

Comment: @JackTurky: yeah default player is wmplayer and I am using win 7

Comment: @Dee: Please post the stacktrace. Can you manually open the file (if Windows 7, without admin previliges)?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1- Don't forget to include :

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
```

2- Make sure the file exists :

```
if (f.exists())
   if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
     Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
```

Comment: The [exceptions thrown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9239693/418556) by `Desktop` should reveal 'missing file' & various other things, if handled & reported properly.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but since he (or she) doesn't tell us what is the error, I suggest the most basic solutions first :)

Comment: He?  It is best not to presume the sex of a poster.  I claim to be 'Andrew', but you can't prove that I'm not really 'Andrea'.    ;)

Comment: Hahaha, whatever :P the person who is asking, and to please you, I'm going to edit my previous comment. ;)

Comment: Thanks man (or human :P) I guess with 30456 reputation, it would be useless if I +1 you too, but I'm still going to do it.

Comment: the error thrown is IOException:Failed to open file:file path. Error message: Access is denied

Comment: @Cookiki For what it's worth, comment upvotes don't increase reputation.