# Can you program external application from Java/C++ app.?

Tags: java, c++

Can you program external application from Java app.?

I know this is a wierd question but lately I really need to do it.

So the lets say I have "VLC" player or MPC or whatever it is, I want to be able to create a Java/C++  application or whatever it is to control the application such as play the video, pause the video and stuff.

If it possible please let me know and how.

Comment: Would be easy if your application provides a command line interface. Otherwise, it depends ...

Comment: *"create a Java/C++ application or whatever it is"*  It would be better to clarify the language choice.  Java can achieve that (poorly) using the `java.awt.Robot` but you would typically look to something closer to the OS, like C++, for this type of functionality.

Comment: yeah, lets assume the application doesn't have command line interface, and about the Robot so i can click buttons on an external app with it ?

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible with VLC. Look here: http://wiki.videolan.org/Java_bindings as well as here: [how to control VLC by java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768397/how-to-control-vlc-by-java)

For MPC, I don't know of any resources that can be used to do so. You can at least launch it to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: sadly i know about vlcj but i want something for other applications too

Comment: @user2580624 Then you need to take a look at JNI/JNA and hope that the applications provide some kind of library access

Comment: @2580624 : it is only possible if the Application provides an interface for it to be controlled.

Answer (score 0):

To start (execute) an external application you should use  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params);
or ProcessBuilder class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

See [Execute external program in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java) for more information.

To send key strokes to another application you could use the "Robot" class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Answer (score 0):

What is expected is to have access to interface to do these operations, you can get some references from http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/ 
This is java api for controlling the VLC instance embedded in AWT.

Comment: sadly i know about vlcj but i want something for other applications too, such as "internet download manager"

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, What you want for other applications?

Comment: if you know Internet Download manager there is an option to add mass url, i wanna create an app to do that.

also for MPC i want to be able to forward or backward the video...

i know its not easy but i really wanna do this

Answer (score 0):

I have found this site that describes how to run external programms from java 
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Comment: well i did read the whole topic, its all about cmd, i want GUI control...

Comment: I am sorry i did get it wrong.