# What's a good alternative to Xuggler as its development has haulted?

Tags: java, video, xuggler

Xuggler has been discontinued and the maven repository no longer exists. Is there a good alternative out there for video encoding/decoding? Or will Xuggler suffice even though it has stopped being maintained?

Answer (score 5):

In terms of Java based API, I have been doing some search for my video encoding/decoding, i only ended up to find xuggler was the still best choice regardless of its  development stopped, popular open source library like [RED5](http://red5.org/) still uses xuggler underneath, for encoding/decoding. Author of xuggler has started a new github library called [humble-video](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video) I am not quite sure how far extend this has gone. Probably you maycan check that too.

Possible other option you may consider is [vlcj](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj), it is just a java wrapper over vlc, which can be used for transcoding

Comment: I'll take a look into vlcj and keep up to date with humble. Going to go ahead and use Xuggler for now as I'm having trouble finding a good alternative. Thanks.

Comment: I have tested with vlcj and it has issues for long time running videos. Also, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768397/how-to-control-vlc-by-java for others having the same observations.